# Displaying a list of category posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to place post links by category, for example:

> Category:
>
> Category Description: lorem ipsum
>
> - post link 1
> - post link 2
> - post link 3

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$args=array(
    'type' => 'courses',
    'taxonomy' => 'study_type',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories=get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<h3 class="study-tax-title">'. $category->name .'</h3>';
    echo '<p>'. $category->description . '</p>';
    /*List of links should be here*/
}
```

Do I need to put another array and do a wpquery or can I echo something through the `get_categories` array?

UPDATE:

Here is how I registered my CPT's and Tax's:

```
<?php

    if ( ! function_exists('custom_course_post_type') ) {

    // Register Custom Post Type
    function custom_course_post_type() {
      $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Courses', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Course', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Courses', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Courses', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'New Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Courses', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No Courses found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No Courses found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
      );

      $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => 'courses',
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
      );

      $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'courses', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Course information pages', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'vendors', 'level', 'study_type', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'query_var'           => 'course',
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
      );

      register_post_type( 'courses', $args );
    }

    // Hook into the 'init' action
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_course_post_type', 0 );

    }

    ?>
     <?php register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'study_type', 'courses' ); ?> 
     <?php register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'vendors', 'courses' ); ?> 
      <?php register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'level', 'courses' ); ?> 
    <?php

    add_action('init', 'course_taxonomies', 0);

    function course_taxonomies(){
      register_taxonomy(
          'study_type',
          'courses',
          array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Area of Study',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true
            )
        );
      register_taxonomy(
          'vendors',
          'courses',
          array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Vendors',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true
            )
        );
       register_taxonomy(
          'level',
          'courses',
          array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Level of Study',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true
            )
        );
    }
    ?>
```

****Here is my updated code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'type' => 'courses',
    'taxonomy' => 'study_type',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<h3 class="study-tax-title">' . $category->name . '</h3>';
    echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';
    /* List of links should be here */

    $filtered_posts = query_posts('cat=' . $category->cat_ID);
    if ($filtered_posts) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($filtered_posts as $post) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as below:

```
$args = array(
    /* 'type' => 'courses', */ 
    /* 'taxonomy' => 'study_type', */ // this only work if you have study_type as taxonomy, default taxonomy is category
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<h3 class="study-tax-title">' . $category->name . '</h3>';
    echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';
    /* List of links should be here */

    $filtered_posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 3, 'category' => $category->cat_ID));
    if ($filtered_posts) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($filtered_posts as $post) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

*** Updated Code with `tax_query` :

```
$args = array(
    'type' => 'courses',
    'taxonomy' => 'study_type',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<h3 class="study-tax-title">' . $category->name . '</h3>';
    echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';
    /* List of links should be here */

    $filtered_posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'courses',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $category->taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $category->term_id
                )
            )
        )
    );
    if ($filtered_posts) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($filtered_posts as $post) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I placed it in my code and it displayed my generic post type categories.  Do you have any idea on how to make it display for a CPT of "Courses" and a taxonomy of "study_type"?  Thanks again for everything!

Comment: Use your `$args=array(
    'type' => 'courses',
    'taxonomy' => 'study_type',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);` it should work, answer updated

Comment: That displayed the Category name and description but not the links :( I edited my original question with my functions for registering the cpt and tax's.  Again, I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: If category name and description is displaying then it should work for links also, may be `$category->cat_ID` is not set. Please add one sample `var_dump($category)` from `foreach` in question / OP

Comment: I uploaded it to my question.

Comment: Looking at `var_dump` `cat_ID` is 46 and category `name` is `Coporate`, make sure you have published posts in `Coporate` category

Comment: So how do you think I should display the links for each Cat?  There are post in that cat.

Comment: As `get_posts` is not working for you try `query_posts`, replace `$filtered_posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 3, 'category' => $category->cat_ID));` with `$filtered_posts = query_posts('cat=' . $category->cat_ID);` and try

Comment: I placed my updated code at the bottom of my question and, unfortunately, it did not work.   I was going over the docs for 'query_posts' and it looks like it is being called correctly.  I am so lost right now.

Comment: Try using get_category_link() to display the category's link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link

Comment: Try `Updated Code:` in my answer

Comment: Manoj I updated my code and it is now displaying "No post found for category name = Coporate, category id = 46" and this continues for each category.  I have double checked and the Cat id's and names are matching up. Also I made sure that all cats have posts.  I feel we are close.  Thank you so much for all your work.

Comment: I think problem is related to `taxonomy` Try `query_posts(array('taxonomy' => $category->taxonomy));`

Comment: When I replace 'taxonomy' with 'study_type' it gives me the same message but if I leave 'taxonomy' in there it spits out the general post types links. Also, if I try and use a different custom taxonomy it gives me the same 'No posts found for cat name' error message.  Do you think that it has something to do with how I registered my CPT or taxonomy?

Comment: Try `query_posts('cat=' . $category->cat_ID . '&post_type=courses');` ** Updated Code: in answer

Comment: That did not work either.  I spent a bunch of time learning about WP_Query last night but I can't figure out how to make that work.

Comment: I have found the solution, You need to use ``tax_query` for `taxonomy`, answer updated try  *** Updated Code with `tax_query`

Comment: YES! THAT WORKED.  Thank you so much for your help!!!  I can't tell you what this means to me.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display posts for one category you have to use "**get_posts**" function (you have many examples here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

But you can try to add :

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'category' => id_number_of_your_category );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
echo "<ul>";
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
   <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; 
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Hope it's what you were looking for and will help you !

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Where would you recommend I place that and do I need to echo out the HTML after the foreach?  Also, can I am using a CPT and Taxonomy so can I put that somewhere in that array.  Sorry to get specific but I am really lost.  Just when I think I have a solution to this it seems to go fleeting.